# How to dynamic insert the header and footer of mainpage.html on other pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I looked for many examples of how to display the same header and footer from one page to others dynamically without having to repeat the same html code and style.

And unfortunately I couldn't find a clear example of doing this, I've seen that it's possible using PHP, but I haven't found any practical examples.

I will be very grateful if anyone can give me an example or an article about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use include() for php, you have the header in one page and your footer in other.
header.php
somthing like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
```

footer.php

```
<footer>
  <p>Author: Hege Refsnes</p>
  <p><a href="mailto:hege@example.com">hege@example.com</a></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

every other page

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<div>
your content...

</div>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

Comment: `include` is not a function. Should be like `include 'header.php';`

Comment: sorry should be <?php include('header.php');?>
<?php include('footer.php');?>
also following your path

Comment: No, you should get rid of the parentheses. `include` is not a function.

Comment: @SaidSalomon thank you very so much, it is exactly wich i've been searching.

Comment: Yes include is not a function, it's an expression, be aware of it.

Comment: in reality, include not appears be function and not appears be expression, but yes a declaration.